# Sitecore 8: First Name & Last name fields not populated in List Manager

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers

I'm working on Sitecore 8 rev 150621. 
I have added a save action to Sitecore WFFM form to add user to a list in the Sitecore List Manager.
When I submit the form the user is getting added to the selected list but the First name and Last name fields of the list inside the List Manager is not getting populated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To populate the details on the `Contact List` you need to store them against the Contact's record in xDB by using the `Update Contact Details` `Save Action` on your Form.

Doing so will make their First name, Last Name appear in the `Contact List` and any other information you want to store appear in the `Experience Profile`.

On the `Update Contact Details` save action you will be able to select the fields from the from and which field in xDB should they be stored against.

[image]

For your First Name field, click in the adjacent Textbox and click through to `Facets > Personal > First name`. And then repeat only selecting Surname for the last name field.

The names of your contacts will appear in the Contact List after that.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this ? Because when I add this save action it breaks one of our custom save actions in the WFFM form.

Comment: Not really, you'd ultimately produce the same functionality. Your custom code shouldn't break by using other out-of-the-box save actions. You should aim to resolve the issue with your custom save action, posting a question about it if you require help